# Is there any function in GAP finding all maximal elementary abelian subgroup of a $p$-group $P$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, p-groups, computational-algebra

I know how to obtain all subgroups of a group in GAP. Is there any function in GAP (or algorithm that I could implemnt myself) for obtaining all maximal elementary abelian subgroups of a $p$-group $P$?

Comment: Do you need elementary abelian subgroups which are not contained in a larger elementary abelian subgroup, or do you need maximal subgroups which are elementary abelian? I'd understand the question as the former, but just to check.

Comment: Yes,  you understand it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ready-made function that does this. As for implementing it yourself, clearly you can restrict to the $p$-Sylow subgroups. For each such subgroup, you could use the cyclic extension method, restricting to elementary abelian subgroups for extension, to find all elementary abelian subgroups. For example:

```
gap> g:=PrimitiveGroup(100,4);Size(g);
HS:2
88704000
gap> s:=SylowSubgroup(g,2);
<permutation group of size 1024 with 10 generators>
gap> lat:=LatticeByCyclicExtension(u,IsElementaryAbelian);;
gap> reps:=List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(lat),Representative);;
gap> reps:=Filtered(reps,IsElementaryAbelian);; # the filter does not eliminate wrong candidates
gap> List(reps,Size);
[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
  4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 ]
```

Then fuse under the group:

```
gap> reps:=List(SubgroupsOrbitsAndNormalizers(g,reps,false),x->x.representative);;
gap> List(reps,Size);
[ 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8 ]
```

Finally (testing for conjugacy with maximal subgroups) one could filter out those that are not maximal.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of "LatticeByCyclicExtension". I was planning to do so by checking each  subgroup of $P$, which is a very bad algoritihm.

Comment: Is there any nice book for GAP which you can suggest me?

Comment: Some resources, and links to further collections of other resources are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104195/which-resources-are-available-to-self-study-gap/369307#369307) - of course including books by @ahulpke.

Comment: Thank you again.

Comment: Why the function reps:=List(MaximalSubgroupsLattice(lat));; create an error? to find the maximal ones?

Comment: Rightnow I can only check the maximal ones by checking their centrilazer, I hope there is a more efficient way.