# Groups, Algorithms and Programming (GAP 4) lack of functions

Tags: group-theory, gap, programming

I am a newbie in using of GAP. To learn it I downloaded a book "Groups, Algorithms and Programming" (subtitle GAP 3.4.4 of 20 Dec. 1995, gap3-jm of 19 Feb. 2018) and also Reference Manual of GAP 4. I see that in the last version (GAP 4) many functions are absent comparing to GAP 3. For example, CoxeterGroup and many others. How it might be explained? I think that more later versions should be improved versions of the previouos one.

Comment: You might be interested in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104195/which-resources-are-available-to-self-study-gap/369307#369307) with links to some resources helping to learn GAP. GAP 3 was retired at the end of 90s and replaced by GAP 4, so learning from that old manual is not the best way to learn GAP today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAP4 is a totally different version of GAP. It looks similar to GAP3, but there are some significant changes to how various objects are treated in the system. As such, previous packages developed for GAP3 often don't work in GAP4 and have to be rewritten. Some packages were never ported over to GAP4 (particularly a lot of Lie theory stuff done by Jean Michel, for example) and so if you want to do a lot of Lie theory work, you need to stick with GAP3. Other commands have been hived off into separate packages that have their own documentation, to make GAP more modular.

Depending on what you want to do with Coxeter groups you might be fine with GAP4 or GAP3, need only GAP4, or need only GAP3.